# Auto login to a webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, authentication, webbrowser-control

Hi I am working on a forum project, currently I have a win form that allows the user to login to the forum - this part works fine.

After the user logs in I want a new form to open that will display the forum, how can I use the login details the user entered - pass them to the login form for the website to the user is automatically logged in so to speak

This is the code I am using for user login

```
    If forumLogin.Verify(RadTextBoxUser.Text, RadTextBoxPass.Text) Then
```

I am using SMF forums not usre how I can pass RadTextBoxUser.Text and RadTextBoxPass.Text to the new form.

I cam accros this code which looked promising

```
 Public Class Browser


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Part 1: Load Yahoo login page in Form_Load event  
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://websiteurl/")
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    'Part 2: Locate the Username TextBox and automatically input your username  
    '<INPUT class=yreg_ipt id=username maxLength=96 size=17 name=login>  
    Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Input")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        Dim controlName As String = curElement.GetAttribute("id").ToString
        If controlName = "username" Then
            curElement.SetAttribute("Value", LoginForm.RadTextBoxUser.Text)
        End If
    Next

    'Part 3: Locate the Password TextBox and automatically input your password  
    '<INPUT class=yreg_ipt id=passwd type=password maxLength=64 size=17 value="" name=passwd>  
    theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Input")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        Dim controlName As String = curElement.GetAttribute("id").ToString
        If controlName = "passwd" Then
            curElement.SetAttribute("Value", LoginForm.RadTextBoxPass.Text)
        End If
    Next

    'Part 4: Locate the "Sign In" Button and automatically click it  
    '<INPUT type=submit value="Sign In" name=.save>  
    theElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Input")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        If curElement.GetAttribute("value").Equals("Sign In") Then
            curElement.InvokeMember("click")
            'Javascript has a click method for we need to invoke on the current submit button element.  
        End If
    Next
End Sub

End Class
```

Code taken from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0b77ca8c-48ce-4fa8-9367-c7491aa359b0/yahoo-login-via-systemnetsockets-namespace?forum=vbgeneral

I get an error when the browser loads object doesn't support this property method?

http://prntscr.com/3xygks

Any suggestions?

Ok so I got it working

On a slightly different note you used to be able to re-arrange where the forms would appear when your program runs I don't see that option in VS2012?

Comment: If you put code that is not yours you have to attribute it

Comment: By the way, What is the problem you have? Can you tell us what you've tried, please?

Comment: The problem is the WebBroser controls throws an error object doesn't support this property method?

Comment: I suppressed script errors so I don't get the error this is the page I want the browser to auto login too http://saunders-solutions.com/FlashCracks/

Comment: Ok so it looks like I am getting somewhere I am now receiving a nullReferance when clearly their is data available see this image http://prntscr.com/3y1gcv